# php app on new server and getting error "failed to open stream: "

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to get a PHP app running on a new server.

When i try to load any of the pages i get the error

> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   'D:!www\api2.domain.com\current\www\web/../../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   D:!www\api2.domain.com\current\www\web\index.php on line 5

The file exists in the location that is being called out (fyi "current" is a symlink)

if i put a simple phpinfo.php in the folder (which is the doc root) D:!www\api2.domain.com\current\www\web\phpinfo.php
this works fine.

This is a Yii app but i do not think it is the framework that is having issues?

the vhost looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName stage-api2.domain.net
DocumentRoot D:/!www/api2.domain.com/current/www/web
ServerAdmin serveradmin@domain.com
ErrorLog  E:/logs/api2.domain.com-error.log
CustomLog E:/logs/api.domain.com-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

> (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')

So is this something? I am not sure where this is set. My php is D:\PHP

I inherited the directory structure so that can not change

Thanks for any help

Comment: `D:!` D colon Shreek????? Thats not right surely

Comment: The include path is a parameter in the `php.ini` file

Comment: what's D:/!www and what's E:/logs/? and why are you running php and yii from a windows server? if you're running an iis windows server, why not use asp or .net?

Answer (score 0):

Correct this line in your Virtual Host definition

```
DocumentRoot D:/!www/api2.domain.com/current/www/web
```

to

```
DocumentRoot D:/www/api2.domain.com/current/www/web
```

i.e. remove the `!`

Or if such a folder actually exists remove the `!` from the folder name and then fix the DocumentRoot

Comment: Wow, eagle eyes, @RiggsFolly!  I would NEVER have seen that.  Many years ago, 10+ programmers stared at a FORTRAN statement where someone had accidentally put GOT0 (gee-oh-tee-zero) instead of GOTO, and NOBODY recognized it until--ACCIDENTALLY--I happened to look at the punched holes in the card and said, "hey, why don't those two Os match?"

Comment: @BruceDavidWilner **Punched cards** Haaaa, someone else that remembers punch cards. Oh the good old dayz

Comment: @BruceDavidWilner You avatar ... may be you... but it sure aint a recent picture

Comment: Sorry, the brainiac that designed this app that i have inherited and have to maintain used !www(with the bang) on windoze and that can not be changed.

Comment: @Bruce: The "!" stands out like a sore thumb to me.

Comment: Ok so if this site was working, can we assume this error is happening to some new code you have added?